# how add data attribute in jQuery dynamic select box?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery dynamic selects plugin.

I want add  data attribute to sum(+) selected options

```
Ex. `<option value="MA" data-price="57">57</option>`
```

https://github.com/corbosman/jquery-dynamic-selects/blob/master/datasupplier.php

Comment: ex. <option value="MA" data-price="57">57</option>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It might work.

```
var example = $('#example option:selected').attr('data-price');
```

Comment: but in datasupplier.php  file how set  data attribute value

Comment: $("form").onChangeLoad({
 var example = $('#example option:selected').attr('data-price');
});

Comment: i did not understand .$towns = array();
$towns['MA']['BARN']['CHA'] = "Chatham";   how set "Chatham" data-price  example is 100

Comment: i want add option data attribute and in datasupplier.php file set data attribute value i want sum option value like this http://jsfiddle.net/uHddF/

Comment: Can you explain ?